# Is promiscuous mode needed for proxy arp?

Tags: raspberry-pi, raspbian, proxy-arp

**edit:** I have found that this is a duplicate of [Why ARP Response only when network adapter in promiscuous mode?](https://superuser.com/q/1298232/879258).

---

I use a Raspberry Pi 3B+ with Rasbian Stretch and set it up with proxy arp following the tutorial from Debian: [Bridging Network Connections with Proxy ARP](https://wiki.debian.org/BridgeNetworkConnectionsProxyArp) to "bridge" eth0 to wlan0. According to this it is easy to set up proxy arp with:

```
rpi3 ~# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/conf/all/proxy_arp
rpi3 ~# echo 1 > /proc/sys/net/ipv4/ip_forward
rpi3 ~# ip route add 192.168.10.60/32 dev eth0
```

`192.168.10.60` is the client on eth0 that should be "bridged" to wlan0.

But it doesn't work. I have to enable promiscuous mode on wlan0 to get it to work but could not find any hints to do this.

```
rpi3 ~# ip link set wlan0 promisc on
```

Is promiscuous mode needed for `Stretch`? If not, how can I avoid it?

**updates:**
Checked that `rp_filter` is set to 0.
`hostapd` is not installed. `wlan0` is in client mode and managed by `wpa_supplicant`.

Comment: have you set rp_filter to 0?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro I haven't touched that settings but checking them, all possible pseudo files in `/proc/ /sys/net/ipv4/conf/*/rp_filter` contain 0.

Comment: is wlan0 in hostapd/AP mode or just a client?

Comment: @RuiFRibeiro Have updated the question. wlan0 is in client mode.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It seems only to be a problem on wifi from Raspberry Pi. Also a duplicate Question [Why ARP Response only when network adapter in promiscuous mode?](https://superuser.com/q/1298232/879258) uses a Raspberry Pi. Nowhere else in any tutorial can be found a note to enable promiscuous mode for proxy arp. I have verified it on my laptop where proxy arp works without promiscuous mode.

I think this issue can only be fixed by the RASPBERRY PI FOUNDATION and/or its closed source driver manufacturer. Till then we have to live with it.

Answer (score 2):

Aparently, it is not possible to bridge ethernet frames between wireless in client mode and ethernet. e.g. It wont work.

Also, beware of injecting frames from others sources into an AP infrastructure as a client.

> most Access Points (APs) will reject frames that have a source
>   address that didn’t authenticate with the AP.

Comment: I know that bridging wireless to ethernet interface isn't possible on OSI layer 2 because lack of 4addr support. That is the reason why I want to work around this with proxy arp on layer 3. My internet router as access point does not reject frames. It responses. Otherwise I won't get responses in promiscuous mode on the raspi.

Answer (score 0):

## Bridge using ARP-proxy with promisc mode

It is possible to "bridge" connections from WiFi-to-LAN (e.g. on a Raspberry Pi Zero W with microUSB-LAN adapter) having all devices on the **same subnet** (IP-range) using **ARP-proxy** with **promisc mode**.

• **Scheme:**
[Router] <---WiFi---> [RasPi wlan0 <---bridge---> eth0] <---LAN cable---> [Wired device, e.g. computer]

• **Hints:** Provided solutions are based on these excellent sources
[Source #1](https://blog.pgeiser.com/posts/2017/04/wireless-to-ethernet-bridge-with-an-arp-proxy/#poor-man-solution-proxy-arp) by Pascal Geiser

[Source #2](https://willhaley.com/blog/raspberry-pi-wifi-ethernet-bridge/#option-1---same-subnet) by Will Haley

• **Hardware/OS used in these examples:**
Raspberry Pi Zero W with microUSB-to-LAN adapter
Raspbian Stretch Lite (2019-04-08) + Updates

---

### Solution #1 - ARP-proxy via INTERFACES (manual config)

**Note: This depends if your WiFi router supports "IP Layer 3 solution" (Network layer)**

**1)** Assuming Raspberry Pi's WiFi connection to router is already set up and connected

**2)** Install packages

```
$ sudo apt-get install parprouted dhcp-helper
```

**3)** Edit and add the following lines:
Assuming

- **wlan0** is ID of Raspberry built in WiFi card
- **eth0** is ID of wired ethernet card (microUSB-LAN adapter)

```
$ sudo nano /etc/network/interfaces
```

```
# Clone the dhcp-allocated IP to eth0 so dhcp-helper will relay for the correct subnet
auto wlan0
allow-hotplug wlan0
iface wlan0 inet dhcp
  wpa-conf /etc/wpa_supplicant/wpa_supplicant.conf
  pre-up /sbin/ip link set wlan0 promisc on
  post-down /sbin/ip link set wlan0 promisc off
  post-up /usr/sbin/parprouted eth0 wlan0
  post-down /usr/bin/killall /usr/sbin/parprouted
  post-up /etc/init.d/dhcp-helper restart
  pre-up /sbin/ifup eth0
  post-up /sbin/ip addr add $(/sbin/ip -4 -br addr show wlan0 | /bin/grep -Po "\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+")/32 dev eth0
  pre-down /sbin/ip addr del $(/sbin/ip -4 -br addr show wlan0 | /bin/grep -Po "\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+")/32 dev eth0
  post-down /sbin/ifdown eth0

# Set ethernet interface to "manual" mode
auto eth0
allow-hotplug eth0
iface eth0 inet manual
```

**4)** Enable packet forwarding:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/sysctl.conf
```

```
# Find and uncomment this line to enable packet forwarding for IPv4
#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
# to -->
net.ipv4.ip_forward=1
```

**5)** Configure DHCP Relay
DHCP helper will catch requests and forward them to "real" DHCP server:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/default/dhcp-helper
```

```
# Change eth0 by the name of your wireless interface (e.g. wlan0)
#DHCPHELPER_OPTS="-b eth0"
# to -->
DHCPHELPER_OPTS="-b wlan0"
```

**6)** Configure AVAHI
Enabling "reflector mode" will allow clients to browse all the services connected to the bridge:

```
$ sudo nano /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf
```

```
# Find and change the following line
#enable-reflector=no
# to -->
enable-reflector=yes
```

**7)** Reboot RasPi
After reboot, via eth0 / LAN connected  device should get access to the same network of WiFi router.
Note: Working solution depends if your WiFi router supports "IP Layer 3 solution" (Network layer)

```
$ sudo reboot
```

---

### Solution #2 - ARP-proxy via SERVICES (automated script solution)

**Note: This depends if your WiFi router supports "IP Layer 3 solution" (Network layer)**

**1)** Create bash-script with these contents:

```
$ sudo nano bridge.sh
```

```
#!/usr/bin/env bash

set -e

[ $EUID -ne 0 ] && echo "run as root" >&2 && exit 1

##########################################################
# You should not need to update anything below this line #
##########################################################

# Credits to Will Haley
# Mainly based on source: https://willhaley.com/blog/raspberry-pi-wifi-ethernet-bridge/#option-1---same-subnet
# Edited on line #52 by Tomtom: path to systemd for parprouted.service

# parprouted  - Proxy ARP IP bridging daemon
# dhcp-helper - DHCP/BOOTP relay agent

apt update && apt install -y parprouted dhcp-helper

systemctl stop dhcp-helper
systemctl enable dhcp-helper

# Enable ipv4 forwarding.
sed -i'' s/#net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/net.ipv4.ip_forward=1/ /etc/sysctl.conf

# Service configuration for standard WiFi connection. Connectivity will
# be lost if the username and password are incorrect.
systemctl restart wpa_supplicant.service

# Enable IP forwarding for wlan0 if it's not already enabled.
grep '^option ip-forwarding 1$' /etc/dhcpcd.conf || printf "option ip-forwarding 1\n" >> /etc/dhcpcd.conf

# Disable dhcpcd control of eth0.
grep '^denyinterfaces eth0$' /etc/dhcpcd.conf || printf "denyinterfaces eth0\n" >> /etc/dhcpcd.conf

# Configure dhcp-helper.
cat > /etc/default/dhcp-helper <<EOF
DHCPHELPER_OPTS="-b wlan0"
EOF

# Enable avahi reflector if it's not already enabled.
sed -i'' 's/#enable-reflector=no/enable-reflector=yes/' /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf
grep '^enable-reflector=yes$' /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf || {
  printf "something went wrong...\n\n"
  printf "Manually set 'enable-reflector=yes in /etc/avahi/avahi-daemon.conf'\n"
}

# I have to admit, I do not understand ARP and IP forwarding enough to explain
# exactly what is happening here. I am building off the work of others. In short
# this is a service to forward traffic from WiFi to Ethernet.
#cat <<'EOF' >/usr/lib/systemd/system/parprouted.service
cat <<'EOF' >/etc/systemd/system/parprouted.service
[Unit]
Description=proxy arp routing service
Documentation=https://raspberrypi.stackexchange.com/q/88954/79866
Requires=sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlan0.device dhcpcd.service
After=sys-subsystem-net-devices-wlan0.device dhcpcd.service

[Service]
Type=forking
# Restart until wlan0 gained carrier
Restart=on-failure
RestartSec=5
TimeoutStartSec=30
# clone the dhcp-allocated IP to eth0 so dhcp-helper will relay for the correct subnet
ExecStartPre=/bin/bash -c '/sbin/ip addr add $(/sbin/ip -4 -br addr show wlan0 | /bin/grep -Po "\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+")/32 dev eth0'
ExecStartPre=/sbin/ip link set dev eth0 up
ExecStartPre=/sbin/ip link set wlan0 promisc on
ExecStart=-/usr/sbin/parprouted eth0 wlan0
ExecStopPost=/sbin/ip link set wlan0 promisc off
ExecStopPost=/sbin/ip link set dev eth0 down
ExecStopPost=/bin/bash -c '/sbin/ip addr del $(/sbin/ip -4 -br addr show wlan0 | /bin/grep -Po "\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+\\.\\d+")/32 dev eth0'

[Install]
WantedBy=wpa_supplicant.service
EOF

systemctl daemon-reload
systemctl enable parprouted
systemctl start parprouted dhcp-helper
```

**2)** Execute the bash-script (check output for any errors):

```
$ sudo bash bridge.sh
```

**3)** Reboot RasPi
After reboot via eth0 / LAN connected  device should get access to the same network of WiFi router. Note: This depends if your WiFi router supports "IP Layer 3 solution"

```
$ sudo reboot
```

---

### General notes:

- ARP-proxy **requires support** by the WiFi router for "IP Layer 3 / Network layer"-capabilities (guess you just can try and find out).
- Preferred solution via WDS (topic has not been dealt with here) for providing a bridge-solution on the same subnet requires WDS-support of the WiFi chip **and** the WiFi router. You can check WiFi chip of your Raspberry Pi for WDS-support with

```
$ iw list
```

in section **Supported interface modes**

```
Wiphy phy0
...
    Supported interface modes:
         * IBSS
         * managed
         * AP
         * AP/VLAN
         * WDS
         * monitor
         * mesh point
...
```

If **WDS** is **not distinctly listed** here, then WDS is **not supported** by the WiFi chip (Raspberry Pi Zero W doesn't support WDS).